# jFugue + Gervill: using different soundbanks the sounds doesn't change

Tags: java, javasound, jfugue, gervill

I'm trying to use jFugue + gervill to create music with Java 7. I've the following code

```
Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("/home/morelli/tmp/SoundBanks/JR_elepiano.sf2"));
    Synthesizer synt = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    synt.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);
    synt.open();
    Player player = new Player(synt);
    Pattern pattern = new Pattern("$PP=0 T120 V0 I42 C4ww V1 I[PP] C5w+E5qq_G5qq C5w+E5qq_G5qq C5w+A5qq_g5qq C5w+A5qq_g5qq V2 I43 G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q V9 81q");

    Rhythm rhythm = new Rhythm();
    rhythm.setLayer(1, "O..oO...O..oOO..");
    rhythm.setLayer(2, "..*...*...*...*.");
    rhythm.setLayer(3, "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
    rhythm.setLayer(4, "...............!");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('O', "[BASS_DRUM]i");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('o', "Rs [BASS_DRUM]s");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('*', "[ACOUSTIC_SNARE]i");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('^', "[PEDAL_HI_HAT]s Rs");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('!', "[CRASH_CYMBAL_1]s Rs");
    rhythm.addSubstitution('.', "Ri");
    Pattern rpattern = rhythm.getPattern();


    rpattern.repeat(2);
    pattern.add(rpattern);
    player.play(pattern);

    player.saveMidi(pattern, new File("/tmp/music-file.mid"));

   //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(synt.getLoadedInstruments()));
   for (javax.sound.midi.Instrument l: synt.getLoadedInstruments()) {
       System.out.println(l.toString());
   }
```

The problem is that if I change the soundbank, the instruments sound doesn't change and the instruments printed are always the same. What I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution (I think :-)). I've to invert the open and loadAllInstruments calls:

synt.open();
   synt.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);